# How to get Jenkins Build Flow Groovy script's filename from within itself?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

I'm writing a Jenkins Build Flow Plugin script and would like to access the filename from within the script itself (so that if the file is renamed, the script content won't have to change). How can this be done?

Comment: Does `getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path` work?

Comment: @tim_yates, nope. It returns `/groovy/shell`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works when using the Jenkins Build Flow Plugin:

```
build.dslFile
```

It's a private field, though, so there's no guarantee it will work with all versions of the plugin.